# Mixture and Alligation:::

Tags: arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

> A solution contains alcohol and water in the ratio 3:1, 16 litres of
>   the Mixture is drawn off and 12 litres of water is added.11 litres of
>   Mixture is replaced by 11 litres of water.The alcohol and water ratio
>   is 9:13.Find the Intial amount of solution?

**How to solve this sum and please guide the steps? I am unable to proceed sum further?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say initial solution is $4x \, \mathrm{L}$.

Then quantity of alcohol $=3x \,  \mathrm{L}$ 
And quantity of water $=x \,  \mathrm{L}$.

Now out of the $16 \,  \mathrm{L}$ of mixture taken away, alcohol $=12 \,  \mathrm{L}$ and water $=4 \,  \mathrm{L}$.
And again $12 \,  \mathrm{L}$ of water is added.

So, now quantity of alcohol $=(3x-12) \,  \mathrm{L}$ 
And quantity of water $=(x-4+12) \,  \mathrm{L}$.

Again, $11 \,  \mathrm{L}$ of mixture is replaced by $11 \,  \mathrm{L}$ of water.

So, now quantity of alcohol $=(3x-12-\frac{33}{4}) \,  \mathrm{L}$ 
And quantity of water $=(x-4+12-\frac{11}{4}+11) \,  \mathrm{L}$.

By the problem, $$\frac{3x-12-\frac{33}{4}}{x-4+12-\frac{11}{4}+11}=\frac{9}{13}$$

Solve for $x$ and your answer will be $4x$.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for replying this Question.please upvote my question @SchrodingersCat

Comment: @Learninguser You are welcome. However you should refrain from asking for upvotes. If your question is good enough then automatically people will give your question upvotes. Merely asking for upvotes makes one look pathetic.

Comment: @ SchrodingersCat  could you please explain these steps:Again, 11L of mixture is replaced by 11L

of water.

So, now quantity of alcohol =(3x−12−334)L

And quantity of water =(x−4+12−114+11)L. how you done?

Comment: @Learninguser Read the answer carefully. Everything is explained.

Comment: how it becomes 33/4 and 11/4 please explain @SchrodingersCat

Comment: @Learninguser They are respectively the quantity of alcohol and the quantity of water present in 11 litres of the mixture which was replaced by 11 litres of water.

Comment: after replacing 11 litres of mixture , how you are subtracting from the equation 33/4 and 11/4

Comment: @Learninguser I am taking away that much amount of mixture. So I must subtract those parts from the equation.

Comment: How you are getting  33/4 and 11/4  @SchrodingersCat Total 3x-12+x-4+12 = 4x-4,for alcohol 3x-12/4x-4 *11 but i am not getting 33/4

Comment: 1. The answer is quite clear and self explanatory. 2. Read the chapter from which you got this problem; you may be having trouble in understanding ratio and proportions. If latter is the case, then unless you go thoroughly through some proper text, I will not be able to help.

Comment: ok I got it Thank you so Much@ SchrodingersCat Nice Explanation Well Done

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192480/mixture-and-allegation-problems please guide me this